What is the better way to perform resource already exist in AWS secret manager
I am trying to create the secret in secret manager using CFT, but there is no direct way in CFT to check If the secret already exist and then If it doesn't exists then create the secret. (Basically resource already exists check is not there in CFT) so I need to write the custom condition like below.
"Conditions": {
        "CreateProdResources": {
            "Fn::Equals": [
                {
                    "Ref": "isResourceAlreadyExistsFlag"
                },
                "false"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "DatabaseCredentials": {
            "Type": "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret",
            "Properties": {
                "SecretString": "XXXXXX"
                ..
            }
        }

To check whether the secret is already created, I need to use the aws cli command in 'bash' to check whether the secret already exists and pass this flag - 'isResourceAlreadyExistsFlag' to the CFT to create the new secret / not.
I did the research to check any existing aws cli command to check the 'secret already exists' but not able to find any in their documentation. Could some one help in finding the aws cli command / any wrapper code to check the secret already exists please.
Thanks in advance.
Thanks,
Harry

Can you explain what is CFT?

@Philippe CFT is the AWS Cloudformation Template

I would check it in the following way (although I am not really understanding the part with the flag completely and I am not using CFT):
#!/usr/bin/env bash


echo "Checking for secret in AWS SecretsManager ...."

describe_output=$(aws secretsmanager describe-secret --secret-id "$1" --output text 2>&1)
describe_exit_code=$?

if [[ "$describe_exit_code" -ne 0 ]]; then
    # secret does not yet exist
    export isResourceAlreadyExistsFlag=0
else
    # secret already exists
    export isResourceAlreadyExistsFlag=1
fi

Hope that points you in the right direction.
